# MySQL inefficient cross table update between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to port a legacy database (with no primary keys) into a better and more structured database in MySQL.

I'm running this query:

```
UPDATE table a, table b, table c 
SET a.item_id = b.id 
WHERE b.description = c.description AND a.id = c.id;
```

`a.item_id` and `b.id` are both `int(11)` fields, and `b.description` and `c.description` are both `varchar` fields. `b.description`. and `c.description` do not have any keys or indices on them. `a.id` and `c.id` are both primary keys.

Table `a` and table `c` are both tables with 50,000~ rows, and table `b` contains 2000 or so rows. As a result, the triple join statement is taking a long time to run. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this efficiently, so what would be a more efficient way to structure the query?

Comment: hooo thats a lot of table why not try using explicit join

Comment: Explicit join plus index the description fields.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query? Please explain your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should write this using `join` syntax:

```
UPDATE table a join
       table c
       on a.id = c.id join
       table b
       on b.description = c.description
    SET a.item_id = b.id ;
```

This shouldn't affect performance.  However, you should put an index on `description`.  I would suggest:

```
create index on b_description_id on b(description, id);
```

Comment: is there a reason why I should explicitly use the join syntax? does the comma syntax not imply a join?

Comment: @user3705002 . . . The comma syntax *is* a `cross join`.  Under most circumstances, that is not what you really want.  It is better to be explicit.  Plus, you can't express outer joins with that syntax (at least not in an intelligible way).

Answer (score -1):

You could reverse the WHERE clause so it tests for the INT before the VARCHAR, which are easier to compare and will reduce the size of the subset for the description comparison.

```
UPDATE table a, table c, table b
SET a.item_id = b.id 
WHERE a.id = c.id AND b.description = c.description;
```